# dynamic routes in app dir in nextjs13 not working after deploying to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am using NextJs 13 with experimental feature of "appDir"
while deploying to firebase hosting, dynamic routes become static path.
*for example :*
path `app/[slug]/page.jsx` become `http://example.web.app/[slug]`

[image: you can slug is consider as static page]

You can see [slug] is consider as static page

Steps to reproduce

1. create nextjs13 app `npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app`
2. create `app/[slug]/page.jsx`.
3. enable `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks`
4. make sure to enable billing.
5. `firebase init hosting` then `firebase deploy`
6. after successfully deployment, check `http://your-domain.web.app/hello`, you will see page not found but `http://example.web.app/[slug]` is working.

in `firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "cleanUrls": false,
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

in `next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

in `jsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mises firebase can host dynamic website in experimental

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that.

Comment: Has anyone run into the same problem ?

Comment: I am having a seemingly similar issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370307/something-not-working-with-dynamic-routes-in-next-js-13-4-on-firebase). Did you find some good solution?