# Something not working with dynamic routes in Next.JS 13.4 on Firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have been having a little issue for a while concerning dynamic routes in Next.JS.

After seeing a few tutorials an reading some documentation, I have the feeling that what I experiment is not what I should expect. I hope this post will help me by bringing a different look from someone with more experience.

Here is a detailed explanation of how I build a trial app, in the terminal, to reproduce my issue and at the end what I get vs what I expect:

```
 % npx create-next-app@latest
✔ What is your project named? … mytrialapp
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint with this project? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS with this project? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? … No / Yes
✔ Use App Router (recommended)? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias? … No / Yes
Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/mytrialapp.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: app-tw 


Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next
- typescript
- @types/react
- @types/node
- @types/react-dom
- tailwindcss
- postcss
- autoprefixer
- eslint
- eslint-config-next


added 352 packages, and audited 353 packages in 19s

136 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created mytrialapp at /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/mytrialapp

 % cd mytrialapp
```

At this point I edit the file *next.config.js* to make it look like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  distDir: 'the_public_area',
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  images: {
    unoptimized: true
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

And I edit the file *app/page.tsx* to make it look like this:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <h1>The home page !!</h1>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I create two directories:

```
% mkdir app/members
```

and inside it I create one named *[memberID]*, then inside it I create a file named *page.tsx* looking like this:

```
type Params = {
        params: {
                memberID: string
        }
}

export default async function DynamicPage({ params: {memberID}}: Params) {
  return (
    <h1>The Dynamic Page !! ({memberID})</h1>
  )
}
```

I then run the following commands in the terminal:

```
% npm install firebase
% firebase init hosting

    ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
    ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
    ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
    ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
    ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

ou're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

 /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/mytrialapp


== Project Setup

irst, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
ou can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
ut for now we'll just set up a default project.

 Please select an option: Use an existing project
 Select a default Firebase project for this directory: myfbproject-7s3e8 (NisHal)
  Using project myfbproject-7s3e8 (NisHal)

== Hosting Setup

our public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
ill contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
ave a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

 What do you want to use as your public directory? the_public_area
 Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? No
 Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
✔  Wrote the_public_area/404.html
✔  Wrote the_public_area/index.html

  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
```

I edit the *firebase.json* file to make it look like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "the_public_area",
    "site": "mytrialapp",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

At this point everything is ready to try out the app, first in development mode:

After running:

```
 % npm run dev
```

I use the web browser to look at: http://localhost:3000/

As expected I see displayed:

```
The home page !!
```

Then I look at: http://localhost:3000/members/Walt-Disney

Again as expected I see displayed:

```
The Dynamic Page !! (Walt-Disney)
```

Then I go and try in production mode, starting by running the two following commands in the terminal:

% npm run build
% firebase deploy --only hosting

Then I use the web browser to see: https://mytrialapp.web.app/

As expected I see displayed:

```
The home page !!
```

Then I look at: https://mytrialapp.web.app/members/Walt-Disney

But here I see displayed:

```
404 | This page could not be found.
```

While I expected to see:

```
The Dynamic Page !! (Walt-Disney)
```

Can someone spot any problem in what I did while building the app above and explain why I do not get what I expect in production mode ?

Comment: I've looked all-over for an answer to this issue but still haven't found one yet. I hope someone from Google Cloud can provide a solution.

Comment: @Moody. Yes indeed. I have given up on this one myself. One reason is that when I tried my code on Heroku it worked without issue. So I presume this some kind of bug on Firebase.