# React ... preventing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I created a route in my Next.JS app on Firebase and though I intended to be very careful, I get a problem.

First of all here is the code (page.tsx) for the route:

```
'use client';

import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";
import firebase from "../../firebase/initFirebase";
import DrillManage from '../components/drillMng'

export default async function MemberPage() {
  const [memberID, setMemberID] = useState("");
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState("");

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        const memberID = window.location.pathname.substring(1)
        setMemberID(memberID)
    } else console.log('window.location is UNDEFINED')

    useEffect(() => {
        let dbRef = firebase.database().ref('Members')
        dbRef.child(memberID)
        .once('value', (snapshot) => {
            const usrID = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(snapshot.child('UserID')))
            setUserID(usrID)
        })
    }, [memberID]);

    return (
        <DrillManage usrID={userID} />
    )
}
```

And this is what I see in my web browser:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
> Call Stack

I don't see in my code anything which could give raise to some infinite loop.

But I may be wrong. Can anyone spot something I am doing the wrong way? And let me know?

I have also tried the following code, but for some reason that I do not catch userID is never set.

```
'use client';

import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";
import firebase from "../../firebase/initFirebase";
import DrillManage from '../components/drillMng'
import { useRouter, usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

export default async function MemberPage() {
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState("");
    const pathname = usePathname().substring(1)
    const [memberID, setMemberID] = useState(pathname);
    console.log('pathname=',pathname)
    console.log('memberID=',memberID)

    useEffect(() => {
        let dbRef = firebase.database().ref('Members')
        dbRef.child(memberID)
        .once('value', (snapshot) => {
            const usrID = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(snapshot.child('UserID')))
            console.log('usrID=',usrID)
            setUserID(usrID)
        })
    }, [pathname,memberID]);

    return (
        <DrillManage usrID={userID} />
    )
}
```

Comment: OK. How would you do that? I am not using a a router at this point, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s one more issue with your code - you declared your client component as `async`. Async components are currently supported only on the server, and that can also cause infinite re-renders in Next.js. You should remove the `async` keyword.

Comment: Yes indeed that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a state setter (`setMemberId()`) during render. That's big React *no-no*; it will trigger a re-render and enter an infinite loop.

Since you're using Next.js, you should rename your page to `[memberId].js` and extract the value from the router

```js
const { query: { memberId } } = useRouter();
const [userID, setUserID] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  let dbRef = firebase.database().ref("Members");
  dbRef.child(memberID).once("value", (snapshot) => {
    // not sure why you'd need JSON.parse/JSON.stringify
    setUserID(snapshot.child("UserID"));
  });
}, [memberId]);
```

See https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

For information on deploying a Next.js app to Firebase Hosting, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs

---

If you're having issues with dynamic routes, you can still extract the `pathname` from the [router object](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-object)

```js
const { pathname } = useRouter();
```

You can then use your original logic (or something similar) to extract the `memberId`.

Comment: Well, the last time I tried to use dynamic-routes on Firebase I spent a lot of time and failed (though it worked with no problem on Heroku with the same code). So I know what you do is the right way, but it may not work on Firebase.

Comment: Do you mean Firebase Hosting? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs

Comment: Yes I am using Realtime database and Firebase Hosting.

Comment: At one point I gave up after posting this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370307/something-not-working-with-dynamic-routes-in-next-js-13-4-on-firebase and spending a lot of time.
At the time I was able to make my code work on Heroku with no issue.
I may want to give it a second try, but I am cautious.

Comment: @Michel can't say I've ever tried deploying Next.js to Firebase Hosting so I understand your frustration. I've added another option you might try using.

Comment: @Phil_is_on_strike. I am trying to follow your suggestions (see the code addition I made at the end of the post), but it is still not working as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**
The value of the following condition remains `true`

```
typeof window !== "undefined"
```

Which is why the following block of code which is inside the `if` is getting executed

```
const memberID = window.location.pathname.substring(1)
setMemberID(memberID)
```

`setMemberID` changes the state `memberID` and the component re-renders, and the `if` block is executed again in the next render and changes the state again, and the component has to re-render every time the state changes. Which is why it is creating an infinite loop.

**Solution:**
Change the following code

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const memberID = window.location.pathname.substring(1)
    setMemberID(memberID)
} else console.log('window.location is UNDEFINED')
```

to the below code

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        const memberID = window.location.pathname.substring(1)
        setMemberID(memberID)
    } else console.log('window.location is UNDEFINED')
}, [window]);
```

---

**Edit:**
If you are using `react-router-dom` in your project, then you can use

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and inside the component you can change the code to this

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof location !== "undefined") {
        const memberID = location.pathname.substring(1)
        setMemberID(memberID)
    } else console.log('location is UNDEFINED')
}, [location]);
```

Comment: Trying this I get "ReferenceError: window is not defined", on the last line